# Multiple .on('click'... function binded only to 1st <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-mobile

I've got .on('click) function that is working only on first div , because I use variables to control it. Here is the button code:

```
$('.article.active').on('click',function(){

        var $currentArticleInfo = $('.articleInfo.active');
        var $current = $('.article.active');
        $current.effect('slide',{direction:'up',mode:'hide'});
        $currentArticleInfo.animate({top:0});

    });
```

And JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u5nw3bhz/3/ (I am using 'swipe' method from Jquery Mobile. Switch to 'Toggle device mode')

Comment: See answer below, you should delegate event: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.article.active', function () {
 // do stuff
});
```

Comment: For more about this invocation pattern for the `on()` method, see http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @dark4p It works like a charm, but when you swipe to the next div if you click the content is not showing.  JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u5nw3bhz/4/

Comment: @Emoyaki, you can fix that by calling show(): http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u5nw3bhz/5/

Answer (score 0):

Delegation should be used here

```
$('body').delegate('.article.active', 'click',  function () {
 All_Your_code_Goes_here
});
```

Comment: Check jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) - "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."

Comment: Yes i know but its not deprecated like live() event  !